# how to get html form to be placed in the center and directly under a logo using css

Tags: css, html

I have a form and i want it positioned directly under the logo that
is positioned in the middle of the page. So far, i cant seem to do
more than this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanx.

Thie is HTML code:

```
<html>     
            <body>
                <div id="content">
                  <div id="formwrapper">
                    <div id="image">
                         <img src="infiniteflame.jpg" width="200"height="100">    
                    </div>
                    <div id="form">
                     <form>
                        <fieldset class="account-info">
                         <label>
                            Email Address
                            <input type="text" name="username">
                         </label>
                         <label>
                            Password
                            <input type="password" name="password">
                         </label>
                       </fieldset>
                      <fieldset class="account-action">
                            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                            -----OR----
                             <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login via facebook">
                       <div id="lang_pref">
                          <ul>
                          <li><a href="/?locale=en">English</a></li>


                                        <li><a href="/?locale=ar">العربية</a></li>


                                        <li><a href="/?locale=cs">čeština</a></li>


                                        <li><a href="/?locale=da">dansk</a></li>


                                        <li><a href="/?locale=de">Deutsch</a></li>


                                        <li><a href="/?locale=el">Ελληνικά</a></li>


                                        <li><a href="/?locale=es">español</a></li>


                                        <li><a href="/?locale=es_419">español&nbsp;latinoamericano</a></li>
                          </ul>
                       </div>
                      </fieldset>
                </form>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                   <footer>
                         <div class="copyright"><img src="infiniteflame.jpg" width="15" height="20" align="middle"><br/>Copyright© 2016 PopeeSoft Solutions, Inc.</div>
                   </footer>


                </div>
                </body>
    </html>
```

This is CSS Code:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
#content {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  border:1px solid #00C;
}
#formwrapper{
width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 900px;
  border:1px solid #00C;
    }

#image {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -208px;
  margin-left: -155px;
}

footer {

    background: #eee;

}
form {
  border: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 350px;
}
fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  width:349px;
}
.account-info {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
.account-info label {
  color: #395870;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.account-info input {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
   box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: #636466;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}
.account-action {
  background: #f0f0f2;
  border-top: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
  padding: 20px;
}
.account-action .btn {
  background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
.account-action label {
  color: #7c7c80;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}
ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display: inline;
    }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/popeesoft/tj3vsb6p/

Comment: Please bear with me if the codes are not properly formatted. I really tried to.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of #image id changes solved the issue

```
   <body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="formwrapper">
      <div id="image" align="center">
        <img src="infiniteflame.jpg" width="200" height="100">
      </div>
      <div id="form" align="center">
        <form>
          <fieldset class="account-info">
            <label>
              Email Address
              <input type="text" name="username">
            </label>
            <label>
              Password
              <input type="password" name="password">
            </label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="account-action">
            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> -----OR----
            <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login via facebook">
            <div id="lang_pref">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="/?locale=en">English</a></li>


                <li><a href="/?locale=ar">العربية</a></li>


                <li><a href="/?locale=cs">čeština</a></li>


                <li><a href="/?locale=da">dansk</a></li>


                <li><a href="/?locale=de">Deutsch</a></li>


                <li><a href="/?locale=el">Ελληνικά</a></li>


                <li><a href="/?locale=es">español</a></li>


                <li><a href="/?locale=es_419">español&nbsp;latinoamericano</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <div class="copyright"><img src="infiniteflame.jpg" width="15" height="20" align="middle">
        <br/>Copyright© 2016 PopeeSoft Solutions, Inc.</div>
    </footer>


  </div>
</body>
```

This is CSS:

```
   @charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #00C;
}

#formwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 900px;
  border: 1px solid #00C;
}

footer {
  background: #eee;
}
form {
  border: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 350px;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  font: 14px/1.4 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  width: 349px;
}

.account-info {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}

.account-info label {
  color: #395870;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.account-info input {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  color: #636466;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 100%;
}

.account-action {
  background: #f0f0f2;
  border-top: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.account-action .btn {
  background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.account-action label {
  color: #7c7c80;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: with position set to relative. it sets the image on top of the form. which is one the things i want. The second thing i want is to have all of them positioned in the center of the page.